# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method AlertDialog.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence) on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

**Here is the error:**

> 04-01 10:37:47.077    2310-2326/zonup.asyc D/Create Response﹕
>   {"success":"false","msg":"Please enter email!!!"} 04-01 10:37:47.084
>   2310-2310/zonup.asyc D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM 04-01
>   10:37:47.084    2310-2310/zonup.asyc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: zonup.asyc, PID: 2310
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.AlertDialog.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a
>   null object reference
>               at zonup.asyc.MainActivity$SignmeUp.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:122)
>               at zonup.asyc.MainActivity$SignmeUp.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:70)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

protected String stmail;
protected EditText editText;
protected Button button;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    stmail=editText.getText().toString();
    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new SignmeUp().execute();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
class SignmeUp extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Thanks for your Sign up...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", stmail));



        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://api.php","GET", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            String success = json.getString("success");

            if (stmail != null & success == "true") {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Youre Email Posted..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done

        editText.setText("");
        alertDialog.setTitle("Info");

        alertDialog.setMessage("You have been subscribed o the ");
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // here you can add functions

            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Put AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); above alertDialog.setTitle("Info"); line

Comment: remove  super.onPreExecute();

Comment: Where did you initialize you AlertDialog?

Comment: I have pasted complete code @shvet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather using AlertDialog use AlertDialog.Builder. As AlertDialog is deprected. Also you need to show progressdialog too.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Thanks for your Sign up...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
```

In `onPostExecute` method `dismiss` the progressbar. Also Use AlertDialog.Builder.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done

     if(pDialog.isShowing()){
       pDialog.dismiss();
      }
        editText.setText("");
      AlertDailog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
             builder.setText("");
             builder.setMessege("");
             builder.create().show();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a **null pointer exception** on `dialog.setTitle("Info")` but it appears you really should be calling `pDialog.setTitle("Info")` since the dialog you initialized in `onPreExecute` is `pDialog` rather than `alertDialog`

Answer (score 1):

You Try Codeing you

you try in method onPreExecute

```
  private ProgressDialog PD; 

        if(PD == null){

    //
                        PD = new ProgressDialog(SplashScreenActivity.this);
                        PD.setMessage("Please Wait..");
                        PD.setIndeterminate(false);
                        PD.setCancelable(true);
                        PD.show();
                }
```

and you cloce PrpgressDialog in method onPostExecute

```
if(PD.isShowing()){
                    PD.dismiss();
                    goNext();
                }
```